# postgresql table data movement

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

In PostgreSQL i want to create script which can delete old data of before 1 month from A table(which contain many rows) and insert this data into one new alias table. and i want to execute this script every month.

for that i have created script as

```
insert into B select * from A where date >(now-'30 day'::interval);
delete from A where date <(now()-'30 days.
```

but in some month there is 30 days and in some 31 days .so how can i set this in cron tab to delete exact data and move in alias table.

Comment: Unrelated, but you can avoid listing the same condition twice by using a writeable CTE: `with deleted as (delete from a where ...) insert into b select * from deleted;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Laurenz answer makes much sense and seems to be a good guess of what OP really wants (cron monthly probably means he wants to flush not "older than one month", but of "previous month" so `date_trunc` to month is a case)

Yet answering it the other way (as I understand the original post):

```
begin;
    insert into B select * from A where date >(now()-'1 month'::interval);
    delete from A where date <(now()-'1 month'::interval);
end;
```

will delete not all data for previous month, but same timestamp one month ago, eg:

```
t=# select now()-'1 month'::interval;
           ?column?
-------------------------------
 2017-05-12 07:31:31.785402+00
(1 row)
```

And with this logic you might want to schedule this data purge daily, not monthly - to keep last month data in active table, not "up to two" untill cron fires...

Comment: i want sheduled this in crontab on 5 date of every month so its right query?

Comment: what is 1 month i.e. its count 30 days or 31 days r it takes 5 jun to 5 july

Comment: yes. try `select now() - '4 month'::interval` - it gives you 12 of Feb, despite the fact that we have 28 days in February

Comment: i have another doubt

Comment: what's that doubt?

Comment: its and production db insert the record continuesally..when  execute query that i.e. between 5 jun to 5 july at 5 july night at 00:05 am. that time some transaction execute and same time as insert query that row will insert in bkp table and on next trigger that row agin insert in bkp table .so what to do now?

Comment: please post it as another question to get normal help. but in short - yes inserted rows after you started transactions wont get to your query and will remain till next job run

Comment: my DOUBT IS that insert into B SELECT *  from A where date-'1 month'::interval) whilewhile excutting this queryquery if 2 transactran happen on A table and tgat same will be insertyed inB?

Comment: no - you will insert only those rows that were in A on the moment you started transaction

Comment: at so b table i.e. bkp table is getting all record of A table i.e. transaction table

Comment: 00:00 is nothing different than 12:31 in terms of purging data older then INTERVAL

Comment: and basically i have to table

Comment: sorry - I'm losing your idea

Comment: 2 Tables 1transaction table which contain live data means live transaction generate onw new row2) bkp table

Comment: and as you mention there is no differance between 00:00 and 12:31 but between 12 to 12:30 there will be some transactuon happens that will be inserted in bkp table and on next month same transaction i.e 00 onward insertes into next bkp table

Comment: means duplicated transaction in bkp table

Comment: if you run `begin; insert;delete;end` rows that are inserted after `begin;` happened will not be flushed - they will be added after `end;` - so you wont hit duplicates

Answer (score 0):

run it on the first of every month and write it like this:

```
... WHERE date >= date_trunc('month', current_timestamp) - INTERVAL '1 month'
      AND date <  date_trunc('month', current_timestamp)
```

If your table contains a lot of data, you might want to look into partitioning.